# Exception is Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 ‘other’

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am getting this error when running the below code,

> Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 ‘other’

```py
    def encode(words):
        max_l = max([len(i) for i in words])
        result = torch.empty((1,max_l, 26)).int()
        for word in words:
            ints = (np.fromstring(word,dtype=np.uint8)-ord('a'))
            addition = np.zeros((max_l - ints.shape[0],)) -1
            tr = torch.Tensor(np.expand_dims(np.hstack((ints,addition)),-1))
            tr = (tr[:] == torch.arange(26)).int()
            tr = torch.unsqueeze(tr, 0)
            result = torch.cat((result,tr))
        result = result[1::]
        return result
```

and would like to know how to fix it? Unfortunately, I don't have the full log stack

Comment: I don't think running just this code (the encode function alone) will result in the error. Post the full error. Also, the line number is mentioned with the error, so use that to determine which exact line has caused the error. This will help you debug.

Comment: The general way to fix the error is to type-case a long tensor to float tensor using `.float()` but the tensor which causes the error can not be figured out from the limited logs that you have shared. I agree with @akshayk07 that just the encoder function does not seem to be causing the error and knowing the exact line (which causes the error) would help in debugging.